# multicol has strange horizontal offset when page cut close to end of columns in bidi mode

Tags: multicol, bidi

multicol works great for me, and so is bidi.
this changes for some rare occasions when I change multicolsep.

this is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{bidi}

\begin{document}
\begin{RTL}\RTLmulticolcolumns
\Large
A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A
\multicolsep=9pt
\begin{multicols}{2}\setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}
A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A

AAA AAA AAA AAA

bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb

ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc

DDD DDD DDD DDD
\end{multicols}
\end{RTL}
\end{document}
```

this is the result - using xelatex:
[image: result - 2 pages]

explanation:
my real code uses polyglossia and hebrew text.
my code above uses english letters instead, so it can be tested by users that don't have hebrew fonts installed.
also I removed all the polyglossia and fonts issues, in order to get clean minimal example, and to reduce noise from other packages.
of course, again, my real code has meaningful text in it - here I only placed enough space before the multicols to show the problem.

if I add some more lines to the multicols, so the next page is over 3 lines, the problem disappears.
also, if I don't touch the multicolsep dimension, the problem disappears.
but I need to reduce the vertical separation before and after the multicol, and this bug (feature?) forces me to manually edit the page to push lines down or up.

*EDIT*: well, as David suggested, upgrading the package seems to solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Oh I get [this image on page 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/liYrT.png) which isn't what you show. Which version of multicol are you using?  I have `Package: multicol 2015/03/31 v1.8m multicolumn formatting (FMi)`

Comment: ok. .I see. I have 2014/10/28 v1.8i  multicolumn formatting (FMi). I'll try to upgrade...